# Bootstrap quicklook plugin of another filetype?

Tags: macos, preview, collada, bootstrapping, quicklook

Is it possible to bootstrap a Mac OS X Quicklook for another file type?

For example, if I have a unsupported 3D model type like `.obj` which I can quickly convert to Collada `.dae` then can I quickly convert the `.obj` file to `.dae` and tell Quicklook to use the built-in `.dae` QuickLook?